# Is there any way to bind a click event to a div's left border in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have a div

```
<div id="preview">
</div>
```

Is there any way to bind a click event to this div's left border?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you write a selector to select a border? Is a border an element?

Comment: Short answer is no, but there are ways around doing this. I recommend adding the click event on the div and then checking to see if the mouse coordinate (when clicked) is on the div's left border.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
div {
    height:100px;
    border:4px solid black;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Please try this method

```
$('div').click(function(e){
   if(  e.offsetX < 5){
        alert('clicked on the left border!');
    }
});
```

**Edit** **-** **Better version**

```
$('div').click(function(e){
    if(  e.offsetX <= parseInt($(this).css('borderLeftWidth'))){
       alert('clicked on the left border!');
    }
});
```

Comment: If I was going to do this, I would use the [computed value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value) rather than hard code it. Maybe jQuery has the computed value, I'm not sure and would have to check their documents.

Comment: You can get computed value with this -> `if(e.offsetX<=parseInt($(this).css('borderLeftWidth'))`

Comment: @Rino Raj . Thanks for the answer.  but  one ')' is missing in the if condition, Can you edit the answer. it works.

Answer (score 2):

You have have events only on **elements**. Borders are not elements. But you can make it look like elements by using pseudo elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".border:before").click(function () {
    alert("Hi");
  });
});
```

```css
.border {border-left: 5px solid #99f; padding-left: 10px; position: relative;}
.border:before {content: " "; display: block; height: 5px; width: 5px; position: absolute; left: -5px; top: 0; background: #f00; height: 1em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="border">Hi</div>
```

Or you can go with having a parent element surrounded.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".outer").click(function () {
    alert("Hi");
  });
  $(".inner").click(function () {
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.outer {background: #f00; padding-left: 5px;}
.inner {background: #fff; padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer"><div class="inner">Hi</div></div>
```

If you feel you should not add borders manually, already you will be adding the events with JavaScript. You can create an element on the fly and make it clickable.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".border").wrap("<div class='outer' />");
  $(".outer").click(function () {
    alert("Hi");
  });
});
```

```css
.border {border-left: 5px solid #f00; padding: 5px;}
.outer {padding-left: 5px; background: #f00;}
.outer .border {background: #fff; border: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="border">Hi</div>
```

Or the best way is to use the computed value and events.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".border").click(function (e) {
    if (e.offsetX < parseInt($(this).css("border-left-width").replace("px", "")))
      alert("Hi");
  });
});
```

```css
.border {border-left: 5px solid #99f; padding-left: 10px; position: relative;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="border">Hi</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is but you can make your own border with another div and set a click event on that!

Here is a example:

HTML

```
<div id="preview">
<div id="leftborder"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#preview{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color:black;
border: 5px solid blue;
border-left:0px;
}
#leftborder{
width:5px;
height:100%;
background-color: blue;
}
```

JS

```
$( "#leftborder" ).click(function() {
   alert( "Left border clicked!" );
});
```

the JS part is jquery so you gonna need to include that in your header first.

Comment: This answer is not sufficient. It is possible people will downvote this.

Comment: Thanks for the warning added a example @Grimbode

Comment: No need to complicate the html. answer is posted, http://stackoverflow.com/a/30725885/1479535

Answer (score 0):

Borders are **not** elements, and as such you cannot bind `click` event to it.If you wanted this type of functionality, you would need to place an element at the left edge of the **div**, and bind to that.

Comment: There is always a way. :)

Answer (score -1):

here is an simple example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .preview {
                background-color:#F5F5F5;
                width: 50%;
                height: 200px;
                padding:10px;
                border: 10px solid #FF0000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="el" class="preview"></div>

        <!-- Script at the end -->
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            $('#el').click(function(e) {
                var $this = $(this);

                // Define the border with
                var border_width = 10;

                // Get the offset
                var offset = $this.offset();
                offset.left = e.pageX - offset.left;
                offset.top = e.pageY - offset.top;

                // Size can be used for calculate click on right border
                var size = {
                     'width' : $this.width()
                    ,'height' : $this.height()
                };

                if(offset.left <= border_width) {
                    console.info("border left clicked");
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```