# angular 4+ horizontally resize div

Tags: html, css, angular

I am new to angular 4 and I have been trying to create a resizable div (horizontally) but I am unable to achieve that. 
I want to click grab to resize the div. I want to resize the text area horizontally.Also in the below link the mouse events are applied on document,but i want the mouse events to be applied only on the grabber class click not on the document.Please help me out

Thanks.

I have tried this one  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-text-resizable-zvp3ns?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `(mousemove)="func()"`

```
<div class="grabber" (mousemove)="func($event)" ></div>
```

In your `component` add the function that you writed inside `(mousemove)`
Registers the event every time an item is dragged over this element
***Here is the mouse events***
 **(click)**     Checks for a single click; including the mouse clicking down, and then back up again
 **(mouseover)**     Registers when the cursor is over the element on which this attribute is applied
 **(mousedown)**     Will register the event when the mouse is clicked down, not needing to wait for the click to release
 **(mouseup)**   This event registers when the mouse click is released, so the click down doesn’t need to be done on the element itself
 **(dblclick)**  The double click event will register the event when it detects two mouse clicks in a short timeframe
 **(drag)**  Will register when the item is dragged
 **(dragover)** Registers the event every time an item is dragged over this element

Comment: Tell me if you need more help :)

Comment: Thanks but can you please modify the code in the above mentioned link  to tell me the changes which you are saying

Comment: simply remove all  `@HostListener()` and conect the function to the event for example `(mousedown)="onMouseDown($event)"`

Comment: like this   <div class="grabber" (mousemove)="mousemove($event)" ></div>

Comment: Thanks that really works. But here the grabber class is resizing(move up and down) on placing the mouse over it ,what i should do if i want resizing to happen on clicking the grabber class

Comment: you have also `(resize)="func()"`

Comment: @JasleenKaur If you get your solution can you please update your code on stackblitz I need to check .

Comment: @לבנימלכה (resize)="func()" is not working. Please specify how i can resize my div only on clicking on the grabber class not on hovering over the grabber class as you can see in visual studio code or any editor

Comment: Here is answer only border:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725607/is-there-any-way-to-bind-a-click-event-to-a-divs-left-border-in-jquery

Comment: @לבנימלכה Yes on grabbing the border, the div tag should be resizable. In your above link I,m not getting the resizable property .Please help

Comment: @JasleenKaur Here is answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233180/resize-div-on-border-drag-and-drop

Answer (score 6):

here I created horizontally(right to left) resizeable div using angular 6

```
import { Component, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
<style>
.textarea {
   min-height: 150px;
   border:1px solid #ddd;
   padding:15px;
   position:relative;
   width: 100px;
   float:right;
}
.textarea .grabber{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   margin-right: -15px;
   cursor: ew-resize;
   height: 100%;
   width: 10px;
   border-top: 1px solid #444;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #444;
}
</style>

<div class="textarea"  [style.width.px]='width' contenteditable="true" >

  this is a text area

  <div class="grabber"  ></div> 

</div>`
 })

export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  width = 150;
  x = 100;
  oldX = 0;
  grabber = false;

  @HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
  onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (!this.grabber) {
        return;
    }
    this.resizer(event.clientX - this.oldX);
    this.oldX = event.clientX;
  }

  @HostListener('document:mouseup', ['$event'])
  onMouseUp(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.grabber = false;
  }
  resizer(offsetX: number) {
    this.width -= offsetX;
  }
  @HostListener('document:mousedown', ['$event'])
  onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.grabber = true;
    this.oldX = event.clientX;
  }
  }
```