# How to diagonally divide a square div into 4 clickable parts?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is how to diagonally "divide" a square into 4 parts:

```css
div {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
  border-right: 50px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 50px solid green;
  border-left: 50px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

(result)

[image]

I want to attach an event to each colored area - but of course you can't attach an event to a border. How should I do?

Comment: check the position of the mouse when the click happened and go from there (better would be to use 4 different divs ofc)

Comment: Using 4 divs might be an optimal solution as @Adelin suggested.
Check [this question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725607/is-there-any-way-to-bind-a-click-event-to-a-divs-left-border-in-jquery#30725885)

Comment: Is it possible to put 4 divs in this form? I mean, is it possible to make a real (not just visually) triangle div?

Comment: You might be able to nest four divs inside of one wrapper. Rotate that wrapper 45deg. Then, you could stick that wrapper inside another div and clip the overflow?

Comment: @samuellawrentz I checked the link, but I don't think the answer is applicable in my case.

Comment: You could use canvas, or map

Comment: @TheCrzyMan It sounded nice, but I found that you have to make a (real) slant outline of the original wrapper, which I feel is impossible (clipping path may help though).

Comment: @akai Once you pick a direction to go, please mark one of the responses as "the answer". I personally like Adelin's answer. But I like JS more than HTML/CSS. Personal preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pursue a single div/different logic depending on location, this might help.

I just wrote this in the console of this page:

`document.body.addEventListener("click",(e)=>console.log(e))`

And clicked, in this order, on these portions: `"yellow"`, `"red"`, `"blue"`, `"green"` of your image. ( I held <kbd>ctrl</kbd> while clicking, so that it would open the image in new tab and this page would persist)

The resulting events (4 loggeed, ofc) had a `path` attribute that said on which element I clicked (in this case, principal one was `img`), and the offsetX & offsetY relative to this element

The relation was:

```
{
  "yellow": {offsetX: 18, offsetY: 59},
  "red": {offsetX: 59, offsetY: 25},
  "blue": {offsetX: 85, offsetY 46},
  "green": {offsetX: 61, offsetY: 78},
}
```

So yeah, you could use, from the [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent):

- [offsetX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX)

  > The offsetX read-only property of the MouseEvent interface provides the offset in the X coordinate of the mouse pointer between that event and the padding edge of the target node.
- [offsetY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetY)

  > The offsetY read-only property of the MouseEvent interface provides the offset in the Y coordinate of the mouse pointer between that event and the padding edge of the target node.

And determine where user clicked.

Comment: I will read, thanks. It's perfectly okay to use 4 divs, but as I commented on my original post, I feel that filling a div with 4 divs in this form is rather difficult, maybe.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do it. Nested DIVs. I used wrapper with a a grid to lay them in the 2x2 pattern, then translated and rotated the wrapper. Clipped using the outermost div. Each one is easy to use the `onclick` for, and you don't need to do extra logic. Just a lot more effort to setup.

I've also got this set up so that you can easily change the size of the squares. However, this definitely won't work in IE, but I don't think we really need to worry about that.

[Working codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVdwNe)

```js
document.querySelector(".red").onclick = () => alert("red");

document.querySelector(".blue").onclick = () => alert("blue");

document.querySelector(".yellow").onclick = () => alert("yellow");

document.querySelector(".green").onclick = () => alert("green");
```

```css
.clip {
  --size: 200px;
  height: var(--size);
  width: var(--size);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.rotate {
  height: calc(var(--size) * 1.5);
  width: calc(var(--size) * 1.5);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate(calc(var(--size) * 0.5), calc(var(--size) * 0.5)) rotate(45deg) ;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="clip">
  <div class="rotate">
    <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="yellow">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="green">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [clip path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to make triangles and use some positioning to get them in the correct spots.

```js
document.querySelector('.sq-tri').addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  console.log(evt.target.getAttribute('data-location'))
})
```

```css
.sq-tri {
  display: relative;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
}

.tri {
  position: absolute;
}

.tri-up,
.tri-down {
  width: 5em;
  height: 2.5em;
}

.tri-left,
.tri-right {
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 5em;
}

.tri:hover {
  background-color: lime;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tri-up {
  margin-top: 2.5em;
  background-color: yellow;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

.tri-down {
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%);
}

.tri-left {
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 2.5em;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 50%);
}

.tri-right {
  background-color: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="sq-tri">
  <div class="tri tri-down" data-location="top"></div>
  <div class="tri tri-right" data-location="left"></div>
  <div class="tri tri-left" data-location="right"></div>
  <div class="tri tri-up" data-location="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an SVG as detailed in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835743/using-css-and-html5-to-create-navigation-buttons-using-trapezoids?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**Note**: As each of the elements inside the SVG has an ID, you should be able to target them with JS/Jquery.

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  stroke: #006600;
}

#buttons polygon:hover {
  fill: orange;
}


#top {
  fill: #cc3333;
}

#right {
  fill: #663399;
}

#left {
  fill: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <g id="buttons">
    <polygon id="top" points="0,0 100,0 50,50" />
    <polygon id="right" points="100,0 50,50 75,75 100,100" />
    <polygon id="bottom" points="0,100 50,50 75,75 100,100" />
    <polygon id="left" points="0,0 25,25 50,50 0,100" />
  </g>
</svg>
```